# Why does a name vector on a list of datatables return a list type?

Tags: r, data.table

One of my functions creates multiple data.tables which I am storing in a list so that I can return these tables for use elsewhere in my script. However, once I retrieve the elements from the list they are of type list() and not a data.table anymore.

If I use a numeric vector instead, I do get back a data.table. Not sure what nuance I am missing here that could explain this behavior?

```
DT_1 = data.table(col1=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), col2=c(1,3,6), col3=1:9)

DT_2 = data.table(col1=rep(c("baa","abb","cgg"),each=3), col2=c(1,3,6), col3=1:9)

DT_list <- list(table1= DT_1, table2 = DT_2)

dt1_from_list <- DT_list['table1']
dt2_from_list <- DT_list[[1]]

class(dt1_from_list)

# is a list

class(dt2_from_list)

 #is a data.table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` is still a `list` of `length` 1.  We need `[[` to extract the element of the `list`

```
DT_list[['table1'] ]
```

For more info, check `?Extract`

Comment: aha, makes sense now. Thanks @akrun!